# How do I disable messaging for certain users in Weavy?

Tags: weavy

While having a chat application that acts as a primary source of support, the chances of getting a number of spam accounts messaging is quite significant. To prevent that, is there any way I can disable messaging of selected users in Weavy.

I tried looking in the Weavy documentation regarding this. But I couldn't find a proper solution or a way out. If there is any doc that I have missed, can anyone point it out to me? Or, if there is none, can someone give me an overview on how the process will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of enabling chat for a user is entirely up to you as an app developer. If you don't want a certain user in your application to access Weavy features and functionality, then simply don't add Weavy to your application when that user logs in.